# Java: Generic Interface, instance chosen at runtime

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

I have the following simple interface:

```
public interface ISimmilarityMeasure<T extends ResourceDescriptor> {
    public double getSim(T s, T t);
}
```

and implementations like

```
public class NormalizedLevenstheinSim implements
             ISimmilarityMeasure<SimpleResourceDescriptor> { ... }
```

and

```
public class JaccardCommentsSim implements
             ISimmilarityMeasure<LabelsCommentsResourceDescriptor> { ... }
```

Both `SimpleResourceDescriptor` and `LabelsCommentsResourceDescriptor` extend

```
public abstract class ComparableResourceDescriptor
             implements ResourceDescriptor
```

At runtime, I call the method

```
public static ISimmilarityMeasure<? extends ResourceDescriptor> getSimInstance(){ }
```

which will return an instance "sim" of ISimmilarityMeasure that relies on a specific instance of ResourceDescriptor.

I also create an array `ResourceDescriptor[] candidates` which will hold, at runtime, instances of the ResourceDescriptor type required by the specific ISimmilarityMeasure object.

However, if I try to call `sim.getSim(candidates[0], candidates[1])` the compiler tells me that

```
"capture#3-of ? extends ResourceDescriptor ... is not applicable for the arguments (ResourceDescriptor ... "
```

I use eclipse and if I look at the available methods for sim, it shows me `getSim(null s, null t)`.
I do not understand why this is the case. Should it not be clear to the compiler, that getSim has to expect any ResourceDescriptor and that every object in `candidates` is a ResourceDescriptor and therefore allow the call? Should it not be an exception at runtime if the specific ISimmilarityMeasure expects a certain type of ResourceDescriptor but is handed a different one?

Comment: Can you show some actual flow of your code. Currently what all you are saying is mixing up in my head. I can't get hold of all of them. For one thing, I can't understand the actual signature of `sim()` out there. You have shown us 3.

Comment: Since the interface ISimmilarityMeasure is generic, the signature of getSim(..) is also generic. In the interface it's getSim(T s, T t) and in NormalizedLevenstheinSim, for example, it's getSim(SimpleResourceDescriptor s, SimpleResourceDescriptor t). "sim" is an instance of ISimmilarityMeasure. The specific implementation (e.g. NormalizedLevenstheinSim or JaccardCommentsSim) is chosen at runtime. I admit, it is abit confusing :)

Comment: Well, I'm talking about return type. In interface you have `double`, and then in the middle it is `ISimmilarityMeasure<? extends ResourceDescriptor>`.

Comment: I am sorry, this was just bad naming - the middle one (I renamed it to 'getSimInstance') is a static factory-method to get an implementation. `double getSim(T s, Tt)` is the actual computation method of the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSimInstance()` will return an object of type `ISimmilarityMeasure<X>` for some type `X`. All we know about `X` is that it inherits from `ResourceDescriptor`. On this object, you call `getSim(ResourceDescriptor, ResourceDescriptor)`. However, it's not expecting `ResourceDescriptor` parameters, it's expecting `X` parameters.

While an `X` is always a `ResourceDescriptor`, there's no guarantee that a `ResourceDescriptor` is an `X`, thus your compiler refuses to accept it.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Is there a good alternative to what I am trying to do, or should I parameterize, for example, NormalizedLevenstheinSim with <ResourceDescriptor> and in the getSim() method do an `instanceof SimpleResourceDescriptor` check?